What's the House MD episode where he hired a woman to fake dead to fool the team?
I remember a (supposedly dead) woman waking up and giving a high-five to House.
Which episode was this from?

I believe you are referring to the 5th season episode "Let Them Eat Cake"

Meanwhile, Kutner tells Taub he has started an online diagnostic
  clinic, but used House's name, not his own. Taub blackmails Kutner for
  30% of the profits in exchange for not telling House. Kutner has
  trouble with a patient who insists her breast implants are causing
  problems. The patient shows up at Princeton-Plainsboro to complain to
  House, whom she believes she has been emailing. Kutner and Taub send
  her to the emergency room so Cameron can deal with her. When the woman
  starts singing "Coconut" uncontrollably and bleeding from her ears,
  Chase tells Kutner to ask House to help. Kutner refuses because his
  scam will be revealed if he involves House. Chase agrees to help for
  25% of the profits. When Kutner and Taub check on the woman, they
  discover she died. House furiously confronts them with the patient's
  body on the autopsy table. House blasts Kutner for setting up the site
  and Taub for not stopping Kutner. House does a series of chest
  compressions and resuscitates the patient, astounding Kutner and Taub.
  The whole thing was a prank: House knew about Kutner's website and
  hired the woman to play a patient; similarly, he bribed Chase and
  Cameron to play along. House allows Kutner to continue the site,
  provided he pays House 50% of the profits.

This stuck in my mind due to the "lime in the coconut" part.
From the transcript:

Kutner: House… [House starts chest compressions.] House, she's clearly
  dead.
[As Taub and Kutner watch, DeeDee inhales loudly. They both jump back
  several feet, terrified. DeeDee sits up, laughing as House gets off
  the table.]
Kutner: She was dead.
House: She wasn't dead. She wasn't even sick, you moron. [DeeDee
  raises her hand and House gives her a high five.] Seriously, how good
  was she? No formal training. At least not in acting.
DeeDee: Did you see their faces?

